# Converting PyObject in Python to 2D array in Android using Chaquopy

Tags: android, python-3.x, pyobject, chaquopy

I'm using `Chaquopy` in my android project. I have a function in my python class which it returns a 2D array as a `PyObject` type. Now, I want to convert it to 2D array in my java class. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT :** Here is my Python code :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

def get_python_audio(file_path):
 fs, data_test = wavfile.read(file_path)
 print('data_test:', data_test.shape)
 data = data_test[:, 0]
 data = data[:, np.newaxis]
 print('data:', data.shape)


 return data
```

Comment: What is the data type in the array? And what is the structure of the array itself, e.g. a NumPy array, a list of lists, or something else?

Comment: Actually, it's a .wav file with 2 dimension as i expanded it with numpy newaxis : 

    fs, data_test = wavfile.read('file_path')
    data = data_test[:, 0]
    data = data[:, np.newaxis]

Comment: shape of my array is (16000,1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Chaquopy 8.x and newer:**

NumPy arrays and Java arrays of the same type can now be converted directly. Assuming `get_python_audio` returns a 1-dimensional int16 array:

```
short[] data = yourModule.callAttr("get_python_audio", filePath).toJava(short[].class);
```

---

**Chaquopy 7.x and older:**

The fastest way to convert numerical arrays between Java and Python is to use a byte array.

We'll assume that `wavfile.read` returns a 1-dimensional int16 array, but this technique is easily adapted to other data types. Then in Python, you can do this:

```
def get_python_audio(file_path):
   fs, data_test = wavfile.read(file_path)
   return data_test.tobytes()
```

And in Java:

```
byte[] bytesData = yourModule.callAttr("get_python_audio", filePath).toJava(byte[].class);
short[] shortData = new short[bytesData.length / 2];
ByteBuffer.wrap(bytesData).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer().get(shortData);
```

If your audio has multiple channels, then you'll have to convert each channel separately.

Comment: again, found bytesData as PyObject, not byteArray

Comment: Sorry, fixed by adding a `toJava` call.

Comment: thnq you, it works. can you explain the last line of code?

Comment: It does the opposie of `tobytes`: converting the bytes back into int16s.